# socket.emit causes other functions/variables to be null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

Hey im building a collaborative whiteboard with Konva where you can synchronize the drawings over several connected clients.
Somehow when I add this line:

```
socket.emit('canvas-data', 'hey');
```

Im getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStage' of null
```

Even though it doesnt seem to have to do anything with that variable.
Here is my code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

function App() {

  const [rectangles, setRectangles] = useState([]);
  const [circles, setCircles] = useState([]);
  const [selectedId, selectShape] = useState(null);
  const [shapes, setShapes] = useState([]);
  const [, updateState] = React.useState();
  const stageEl = React.createRef();
  const layerEl = React.createRef();
  const fileUploadEl = React.createRef();
  const [brushSize, setBrushSize] = React.useState('5');
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = React.useState(false);
  const dragUrl = React.useRef();
  //const stageRef = React.useRef();
  const [images, setImages] = React.useState([]);
  const [loadImages, setLoadImages] = React.useState([]);
  const getRandomInt = max => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
  };

  const {transcript} = useSpeechRecognition();
 
  const URLImage = ({image}) => {
    const [img] = useImage(image.src);
    return (
      <Image
        image = {img}
        x = {image.x}
        y = {image.y}

        offsetX = {50}
        offsetY = {50}

        width={200}
        height={200}
        draggable
      />
    );
  };

socket.emit('canvas-data', 'hey');  //this is the added line
  const drawLine = () => {         //The problem is in this function
    console.log('data being sent');
    setIsDrawing(true);
    if(isDrawing){
      console.log(isDrawing);
      addLine(stageEl.current.getStage(), layerEl.current, brushSize);
    };
  };
  
  const eraseLine = () => {
    addLine(stageEl.current.getStage(), layerEl.current, brushSize, "erase");
  };
```

When I remove that line everything works fine. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to check for `stageEl.current` being null before calling `getStage` on it. Also note that setting state is async, which means `setIsDrawing(true);` will not actually set `isDrawing` to true immediately.

Comment: So basically you mean, only when the stageEl.current gets some drawings and wont be null, only after that i am able to do socket emit right?

Comment: Not sure, but `stageEl.current.getStage()` causes the error you mention when `stageEl.current.getStage()` is `null`. So you have to check for whether you emit or not.